# Logic apps cannot handle 'Bad Request'

Tags: azure-logic-apps, http-status-code-400

I'm new to Azure Dev. Trying to check statuscode after generating a request in an 'if' condition. It works fine when I get 200. However, it fails when I get a 400.[image]. Code view looks something like this: [image]
It is a bit weird why I couldn't catch 400. I have seen another way to do i.e. to configure 'RunAfter' and then handle the error but need to know what's wrong with my approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable configure the runafter to run even after the whole workflow is getting failed.

This is how it worked for me. Go to your work flow and click on Menu for that particular action that you want to run even after the before action is about to  fail/ timeout/ skip. In your case it is Condition and then click on `Configure run after`.

[image]

[image]

Here is how my code view looks like
[image]

OUTPUT:
[image]